# How to implement Lookup Tables?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, lookup-tables

I am unable to grasp the concept of the lookup table. 
I am currently working on a project wherein I am using two tables.

1. The first table consists of two columns- name(varchar) and value(varchar).
2. The second table also has two rows- Result(varchar) and value(varchar).

Result is used to store the values which are obtained from a Java code. Whenever the Result of the Java code matches the name in the first table, I need to update the second table with the corresponding value in the first table.
Does using lookup table help in any way? If it does, can it be explained with an example?If not, is there any other way?

Comment: Aren't those already lookup tables basically?

Comment: Is it a rule that a lookup table must have only two columns or something?       And if they are lookup tables, how can I update my tables? Is there some specific code?

Comment: No, not really I suppose. Although in the [strictest definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) you would be using a simple value `x` to look up a complex value `y`. With more complex mappings you start to be in the `Map` region instead of a lookup table.

Comment: You want specific code but you haven't even tagged a specific database.

Comment: In your example I don't see a relationship between table1.name and Table2.result. A lookup up table to hold that relationship would consist of name and result

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake @shmosel. By specific code, I mean is there some syntax for lookup tables that needs to be followed?

Comment: Thank you @Kayaman

Comment: You're talking about completely unrelated things. This question has nothing to do with lookup tables. Seems more like you're looking for triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Just imagine a table `person` with a column `GenderIsMale BIT`. You can set this value to `1` (yes, it is a boy) or to `0` (no, a girl). This was easy in earlier days.

Now we have more categories. According to [this link](http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2014/02/21/gender_facebook_now_has_56_categories_to_choose_from_including_cisgender.html) *facebook* offers more than 50 differing categories...

There the lookup-table comes into play: You create a table which has - as minium - a unique key and a value. In most cases this is an `ID INT IDENTITY` and a `Content VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL`. You can add more columns like `Abbreviation` or any other additional content (e.g. other languages or codes of external code systems [read about *mapping tables* also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37525924/5089204)) directly bound to this value.

The next step is, to take the `GenderIsMale`-column away and replace it with a

```
GenderID INT NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT FK_Person_GenderID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES GenderLookUpTable(GenderID)
```

The person table will store the `GenderID` only, the related values are stored in the side table and can be *looked up*.

The simple *lookup table* is the basic construct of *how to create a relational database model in min. 3.NF  or BCNF* (which should be a minium reuqirement for professional database design).

Comment: I'd say this describes database normalization rather than what a lookup table is.

Comment: no @Kayaman this is what exactly lookup table is - it has short value in a field in main table (there can be many reasons for that, but usually because you can't allow long name in main field) and there is another table - that's the look-up table where you look up real value according to the code in a field in main table

Comment: @Drako When talking about databases, you wouldn't say "this table1 has a lookup table table2". Besides, the poster seems to be looking for trigger functionality, but the whole question got derailed by nonsense. Which you're continuing.

Comment: @Kayaman - question asks how to implement Look-up tables? So you have to agree what a look-up table is to explain it's implementation, if in  your table definition such term does not exist - you have to invent it, cause it's wide used technique when you do for example specific coded messages over network and need name validation - you have main table for  codes and - look-up table where the real values for codes are stored; you can name it as you want - for most that's what a look-up table is and I guess the question was exactly about this cause author writes having problems to grasp this.

Comment: @Drako I know what a lookup table is. The poster doesn't.

Comment: @Kayaman, well, what is a lookup-table for you? Do you speak about internally used index tables for index lookups? In database terminology - at least on beginner's level - a lookup table is a table to *lookup* some values according to a unique id used as FK in some other table.

Comment: I'm wondering why you keep talking about lookup tables, when it's clear from the question that the poster actually wants a trigger to update one table when a modification happens in another. Still, I'd say [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) gives a better explanation without having to go into confusing "beginner level database terminology".

Comment: @Kayaman Did you realise, that the question's title is *How to implement lookup tables?* Might be, that you hit the nail with your trigger idea. Just type in a solution on your own! Might be, that the OP already knows, what I've written (as it is trivial), but the first line of the question is *I am unable to grasp the concept of the lookup table*. Optimistically I'd assume, that OP has read some stuff already... SO is a Q&A platform and not a *I know better than you* discussion area...

Comment: Fair enough. However as your answer does not answer the question (it doesn't even answer the title), in accordance with SO standards I will downvote it as such.

Comment: @Kayaman, My answer does *not answer the question*??? blah blah downvote blah blah ... OMG... Don't wanna switch with you... Please enlighten the audience with your own answer!

Comment: I assume you're the audience, so be enlightened. I even used that term you really like.

Comment: @Kayaman, it's on the OP now to decide which answer really solves his problem. Happy coding and calm down a bit...

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever the Result of the Java code matches the name in the first
>   table, I need to update the second table with the corresponding value
>   in the first table.

That's a perfect use case for [database trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger), which can be used to perform various things when a change (insert, update, delete) happens in a table.

Assuming you're inserting the value of your Java calculations to your `(result, value)` table (let's call it `foo`, and the other table is `bar`), you can write a trigger that replaces the value being written with the value from the other table. Example given for Postgres, if using another db refer to your particular RDBMS manual to see the syntax.

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_value_from_lookup_table() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bar WHERE name = NEW.result) THEN
            RETURN SELECT name, value FROM bar WHERE name = NEW.result;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER lookup_value
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON foo
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE get_value_from_lookup_table();
```

Every time an `INSERT` is done on `foo`, a check is done to see if a row exists in `bar` where `name=result`. If so, that row is inserted, otherwise the insert goes on normally. That's the basic gist of it. The actual solution depends on table constraints, whether you need to handle inserts and updates, etc.